# pd.read_csv question with two different tables on top of each other in .csv

Tags: python, pandas

i have got a csv file that is setup with information on top of information and im struggling to read it into a dataframe.

The raw CSV Looks like:

[image]

I am hoping to get essentially 3 different things:
1) Define the date and company name in the first row
2) Put the summary table (top table) into a dataframe
3) Put the detailed sales table into another dataframe

I tried `df = pd.read_cs(filepath,error_bad_lines=False)` which just gives me the summary table but in only 3 rows due to the first row being only 3 columns. Any ideas on how to read these files? the row numbers for the summary table are not fixed (varies how many rows). Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I suggest in this case you may want to read file line by line and then construct you dataframes relying on line length, as it is different for parts 1 - 3 elements, 2 - 4 elements and 3 - 7 elements.

Comment: Thans alot @kotbegemot. do you have any suggestions / resources to read line by line? Thanks

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks very much @kotbegemot. Will post solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested this is what i used to solve the problem:

```
from csv import reader

with open('*.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    list3 = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) == 3:
            list1.append(row)
        if len(row) == 4:
            list2.append(row)
        if len(row) == 7:
            list3.append(row)
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(list3)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the number of rows you want to read with parameter `nrows` and you can also use `skiprows` to skip reading certain rows in [`pd.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_excel.html):

You can read the `top-table` like below into a df:

Here, you can skip the first row which has some not useful headers and read the next 10 rows which contain top-table's data.

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('test.xls', skiprows = 1,  nrows= 10, usecols = 'A:D')
```

Then the `second-table` in another df like this:

Here, you can skip the rows already read in df1, and read the remaining data from the file.

```
df2 = pd.read_excel('test.xls', skiprows = 6)
```

Comment: Thansk for the suggestion! The number of rows df1 may always be different so i am trying to find a way that would pick up those changes. Will give the solution a try!

Comment: hi @Mayank. Do you have any suggestion as to how to avoid hard coding in the `nrows` and `skiprows` parameters? I am finding each .csv file is different in lengths